# get perl GD to work

Tags: perl, gd, osx-mavericks, circos

I am trying to get the GD perl module to work on my mac. I have installed the gd library

```
$ gdlib-config --all
GD library  2.1.0
includedir: /usr/local/include
cflags:     -I/usr/local/include
ldflags:     -L/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/local/lib
libs:       -ljpeg -lz  -L/usr/local/lib -lpng16 -L/usr/local/lib -lfreetype -lz -lbz2 -lpng16 -liconv
libdir:     /usr/local/lib
features:   GD_JPEG GD_FREETYPE GD_PNG GD_GIF GD_GIFANIM GD_OPENPOLYGON
```

However GD fails the make test

```
$ make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /Users/smithk/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/GD.t ........ 1/12 Testing using png support.
t/GD.t ........ Failed 7/12 subtests 
(less 2 skipped subtests: 3 okay)
t/Polyline.t .. ok   

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/GD.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 12 Failed: 7)
  Failed tests:  2-7, 10
Files=2, Tests=13,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.09 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.13 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/2 test programs. 7/13 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
```

I realize that the GD make test is hit or miss, so if I force install I still can't get the Circos program to work with it. I get the following error when I test GD through circos:

```
Can't locate object method "png" via package "GD::Image" at ./gddiag line 209.
```

Not sure what is wrong...

Comment: Do you have libpng installed?

Comment: I do. And looking at the output of gdlib-cinfig --all, it looks like the gd library is finding it. Its says features GD_PNG.

Comment: I myself have tried to install GD in various ways but the only one I was successful with was by using MacPorts - means you will need to install a local version of perl but that is a good thing as it's probably better not to mess around with the system perl.